# Add characters to the end of a line in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I want to add characters to the end of a line in notepad++. The catch is, it only has to be lines starting with the characters "GNSCT"

Does anyone have a regular expression that can help me outwith this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
Find What: ^(GNSCT)(.*)$
Replace With: \1\2YOURCHARACTERS
Search Mode: Regular expression
```